# Solr indexing - Master/Slave replication, how to handle huge index and high traffic?

Tags: solr, replication

I'm currently facing an issue with SOLR (more exactly with the slaves replication) and after having spent quite a few time reading online I find myself having to ask for some enlightenment.

**- Does Solr have some limitation in size for its index?**

When dealing with a single master, when is it the right moment to decide to use multi cores or multi indexes?
Is there any indications on when reaching a certain size of index, partitioning is recommended?

**- Is there any max size when replicating segments from master to slave?**

When replicating, is there a segment size limit when the slave won't be able to download the content and index it? What is the threshold to which a slave won't be able to replicate when there's *a lot of traffic* to retrieve info and *lots of new documents* to replicate.

To be more factual, here is the context that led me to these questions:
We want to index a fair amount of documents, but when the amount reaches more than a dozen millions, the slaves can't handle it and start failing replicating with a SnapPull error.
The documents are composed with a few text fields (name, type, description, ... about 10 other fields of let's say 20 characters max).

We have one master, and 2 slaves which replicate data from the master.

This is my first time working with Solr (I work usually on webapps using spring, hibernate... but no use of Solr), so I'm not sure how to tackle this issue.

Our idea is for the moment to add multiple cores to the master, and have a slave replicating from each of this core.
Is it the right way to go?

If it is, how can we determine the number of cores needed? Right now we're just going to try and see how it behaves and adjust if necessary, but I was wondering if there was any best practices or some benchmarks that have been done on this specific topic.

For this amount of documents with this average size, x cores or indexes are needed ...

Thanks for any help in how I could deal with a huge amount of documents of average size!

*Here is a copy of the error that is being thrown when a slave is trying to replicate:*

```
ERROR [org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler] - <SnapPull failed >
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Index fetch failed :
        at org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller.fetchLatestIndex(SnapPuller.java:329)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler.doFetch(ReplicationHandler.java:264)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller$1.run(SnapPuller.java:159)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:417)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:280)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:135)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:65)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:650)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:675)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: read past EOF
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1068)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:418)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller.doCommit(SnapPuller.java:467)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller.fetchLatestIndex(SnapPuller.java:319)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: read past EOF
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.refill(BufferedIndexInput.java:151)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.readByte(BufferedIndexInput.java:38)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.IndexInput.readInt(IndexInput.java:70)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$2.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:410)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:704)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:538)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCurrentVersion(SegmentInfos.java:402)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.isCurrent(DirectoryReader.java:791)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doReopen(DirectoryReader.java:404)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.reopen(DirectoryReader.java:352)
        at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexReader.reopen(SolrIndexReader.java:413)
        at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexReader.reopen(SolrIndexReader.java:424)
        at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexReader.reopen(SolrIndexReader.java:35)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1049)
        ... 14 more
```

**EDIT**:
After Mauricio's answer, the solr libraries have been updated to 1.4.1 but this error was still raised.
I increased the commitReserveDuration and even if the "SnapPull Failed" error seems to have disappeared, another one started being raised, not sure about why as I can't seem to find much answer on the web:

```
ERROR [org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter] - <ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:370)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:323)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:396)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:385)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)
        at org.apache.solr.common.util.FastOutputStream.flushBuffer(FastOutputStream.java:183)
        at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.marshal(JavaBinCodec.java:89)
        at org.apache.solr.request.BinaryResponseWriter.write(BinaryResponseWriter.java:48)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.writeResponse(SolrDispatchFilter.java:322)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:254)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.jstripe.tomcat.probe.Tomcat55AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat55AgentValve.java:20)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:837)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:640)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1286)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:703)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:733)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:539)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:560)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:365)
        ... 22 more
>
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/].[SolrServer]] - <Servlet.service() for servlet SolrServer threw exception>
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:405)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.sendError(SolrDispatchFilter.java:362)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:272)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.jstripe.tomcat.probe.Tomcat55AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat55AgentValve.java:20)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:837)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:640)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1286)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

I still wonder what are the best practices to handle a big index (more than 20G) containing a lot of documents with solr. Am I missing some obvious links somewhere? Tutorials, documentations?

Comment: which replication mechanism did you use? java or script-based?

Comment: Everything is done in Java (solr http replication). The master is the data loader and indexes everything, and the slaves replicate the master. The first error "SnapPuller failed" occurred when we added a bunch of documents. The master handled it just fine, but the slaves started failing, supposedly because of the sudden bigger segments to replicate. This is why I was asking for some advice on what was the best way to scale solr, this document has been helpful: http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Scaling-Lucene-and-Solr#d0e410

Answer (score 16):

- Cores are a tool primarily used to have different schemas in a single Solr instance. Also used as on-deck indexes. Sharding and replication are orthogonal issues.
- You mention "a lot of traffic". That's a highly subjective measure. Instead, try to determinate how many QPS (queries per second) you need from Solr. Also, does a single Solr instance answer your queries fast enough? Only then can you determine *if* you need to scale out. A single Solr instance can handle a lot of traffic, maybe you don't even need to scale.
- Make sure you run Solr on a server with plenty of memory (and make sure Java has access to it). Solr is quite memory-hungry, if you put it on a memory-constrained server, performance will suffer.
- As the Solr wiki explains, use sharding if a single query takes too long to run, and replication if a single Solr instance can't handle the traffic. "Too long" and "traffic" depend on your particular application. Measure them.
- Solr has lots of settings that affect performance: cache auto-warming, stored fields, merge factor, etc. Check out [SolrPerformanceFactors](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors).
- There are no hard rules here. Every application has different search needs. Simulate and measure for your particular scenario.
- About the replication error, make sure you're running 1.4.1 since 1.4.0 had a bug with replication.

Comment: Thanks for these explanations. We use 1.4.0 if I remember properly so I'll give a try on Monday when I'm back at work with 1.4.1 and see if this resolves the issue. I'm pretty sure we maxed out the memory on the server where solr runs so we can't get much more improvements on this side. Hence the question on when dealing with more than dozens of millions of documents, is the design we chose (1 master that processes and indexes the documents and 2 slaves for replication and handling the traffic) the ideal one.

Comment: Does 8G of memory allocated for the JVM is considered as plenty? (on a blade that has 10G total). Concerning the QPS, it's not that high, about 5 to 10 QPS depending on the time of the day, but new documents are added to the index every second. Maybe there's no need to scale out, but if we do need to (as it currently fails due to the SnapPull error), how would this be handled if cores are not the right way to go?

Comment: @Fanny: 5-10 QPS is not much. But too frequent commits will kill performance.

Comment: Sorry, upgrading our libraries to 1.4.1 didn't solve the issue. SnapPull failed exception is still being thrown (Unable to download segments_xxx completely...).

Comment: @MauricioScheffer sorry for "re-opening" old post, but as described on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47771564/keep-solr-slaves-in-sync/47785722 we have a situation where we need multiple replicated (not shared!) slaves connected to one master. How can we ensure, that all slaves have exactly the same index version everytime because replication/poll is handled dedicated on each slave?