# Keep Solr slaves in sync

Tags: solr, replication

We have a master-slave setup running Solr 6.5.0. There is a backend process running 24/7 which pushes its data towards the master server. No commit is done on master. The web frontend is accessing the slave. Replication poll interval is 1 hour.

All is fine so far, but now as the traffic grows, the CPU load on slave is really high. I thought the best thing would be to add a second slave to the master and let the web servers connect via existing load balancers to the two Solr slave machines. I think that the two Solr slaves will handle their replication independently and each slave will poll the master at another time.

As the master receives 24/7 new data I'm worried that both machines do not have the same data set/version. Is there a solution with low administration effort to force both slaves polling new data from master at the same time? (I.e. I'm trying to avoid setting up a real Solr cluster as multiple slaves will fit our needs.)

Comment: When you said, that you have constantly pushes of data to master, do you mean it could be really happening like every minute or every second, depending on the event flowing?

Comment: Yes, data is written on master constantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is following, during your poll interval, potentially, your slaves could be out-of-sync. In your case you have 1 hour interval.

The thing which could be done with minimal effort is following, you could **force** replication on slaves at the same time by calling the command:

```
http://slave_host:port/solr/core_name/replication?command=fetchindex
```

However, I'm not sure how often you could call this command, since most likely you couldn't do it every minute or so.

Another possibility is to trigger replication whenever a commit is performed on the master index. You could do this by adding configuration:

```
<str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
```

For more information about it take a look [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/index-replication.html#IndexReplication-CommitandOptimizeOperations)

Comment: As I execute a commit every hour on master this can be used to trigger a replication on all slaves? So this is a master-side trigger? How can I disable slave-side poll interval then? Simply by remove pollInterval setting in config?

Comment: to be honest, im not 100% sure, how to do that

Comment: as per solr documentation, "The master is totally unaware of the slaves." So, in case you're worried about the slaves being out of sync with the master, you can reduce the polling interval.

Answer (score -1):

The traditional master-slave is basically doing rsync over http. So, maybe you can rsync between slaves (and reload cores after rsync).